# is there a legal & valid for facebook login using curl or some none browser (login popup) approach?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-login

I am trying to make facebook application; But, my system will not have a browser support; 
And in order to write and use fb APP, getting access token the first thing that my app has to do is ask user to login on facebook.

As far as I have seen, this call redirects to facebook login, or popup for facebook login.
As I said earlier, I dont have browser; Is there any such mechanism available by facebook that can log the use in using some curl or other kind of API..

Thanks

Comment: No. If this app is only for you, then you can request publishing permissions for yourself in the browser-flow _once_ – and then use your app access token afterwards to publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever authentication mechanism you choose, you will always have to run the users through a Facebook authentication screen, to be rendered on a browser or similar.

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/ for more information.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Cbore, Santos. I got to know that it would not be possible  for login. But, as of the other requirement, I need to ask to you guys. The permissions granted buy user to an application on BROWSER flow is MUST. Or I can get APIs that I can call from client after successful login and ALLOW application required permissions?

Comment: One major doubt I have is, again here too atleast once user has to grant permission to an application using BROWSER flow?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit better? I really can't understand what you're trying to ask there.

Comment: @Santos; I want user to authorize the application and grant the required/asked permissions. For all this general way is to go to "www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=xxxx&scope=permissionsxxx". Now visiting this link will redirect to ask 'ALLow' for granting and authorizing permissions, right? This all is done in browser. I want this all to be performed in non-browser way.

Comment: Wasn't that the original question? I already told you that you can't.

Comment: What you can do is run the user through the browser flow once, and ask for the access token to be extended so you can run calls from the server for longer than 1/2 hours: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: @santos; thank you very much for the prompt reply and patience. I just wanted to verify this. Actualy I read everywhere and found the same answer as you said. Thanks for your guidance